# how can i make image in ui fill the panel

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, unity-ui

I am making an inventory for my game, but I can't make the slot and inventory background fit the entire plane without make the hit box stretched. cant really find any documentation on this so I dont know how to fix my problem.

at first, I messed with the settings but that didn't help I just want the entire I image to move exactly with the panel